# can i able to modify response from mysql server in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**For eg:- The below response is the actual response**

```
   {
        "todo_id": 2,
        "todo_item": "brush ur teeth",
        "schedeuled_time": "2020-03-22T07:14:29.000Z",
        "user_id": 1,
        "is_done": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                0
            ]
        },
        "is_time_passed": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                0
            ]
        }
    }
```

**I NEED TO MODIFY THE RESPONSE LIKE BELOW**

```
  {
        "todo_id": 2,
        "todo_item": "brush ur teeth",
        "schedeuled_time": "2020-03-22 07:14",
        "user_id": 1,
        "is_done":0,
        "is_time_passed": 0
    }
```

**MY CODE SNIPPET**
The below code is nodejs and expressjs which connects MySQL

```
 function getAllToDo(req,res){
        let sql = `select 
                        todo_id,
                        todo_item,
                        schedeuled_time,
                        user_id,
                        is_done,
                        is_time_passed
                     from to_do_table where is_deleted = 0 AND user_id = ${req.body.user_id}`
        let query = connection.query(sql,(err, results)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status":200, "error": null,"response": results}));
        });
    }
```

Comment: The response is a single object or array of objects ?

Comment: Why don't you just change the DB schema to is_done and is_time passed to be boolean and then the query will return true or false for that. Why do you have those attributes stored inside a buffer in DB?

Comment: @QubaishBhatti is an array of objects

Comment: From the name of the attribute It implies that it is simple yes/no a.k.a boolean, is there any reason to not just change the type to boolean and return true or false if the task is done or is postpone?

Comment: @PetrM I can use but I want to try out this way

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a array of objects. Try this

```js
const result = [{
    "todo_id": 2,
    "todo_item": "brush ur teeth",
    "schedeuled_time": "2020-03-22T07:14:29.000Z",
    "user_id": 1,
    "is_done": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            0
        ]
    },
    "is_time_passed": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            0
        ]
    }
}];

const expectedResult = Object.keys(result).map(key => {
 let data = {};
   data = result[key];
   data.is_done = result[key].is_done.data[0];
   data.is_time_passed = result[key].is_time_passed.data[0];
return data;
});

console.log(expectedResult)
```

Comment: It is working fine I want to change the scheduled_time   "schedeuled_time": "2020-03-22 07:14",

Comment: Use Date formatters for that: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Answer (score 0):

This query should solve your problem

```
select todo_id,todo_item,
DATE_FORMAT(schedeuled_time,'%Y %m %d %T') as schedeuled_time,
user_id,
JSON_EXTRACT(is_done, '$.data[0]') as is_done,
JSON_EXTRACT(is_time_passed, '$.data[0]') as is_time_passed
from to_do_table
where is_deleted = 0 AND user_id = ?
```